# UIView Animation with POP framework grow and shrink in same action

Tags: ios, animation, uiview, facebook-pop

I'm using `POP` framework for animations. I want to tap a `UIButton` and have it grow by 5%, then shrinks back to original size. I can get the grow or the shrink to work, but since I haven't used the framework I don't know how to make both happen in one action.

The animation code is below. I'm sending this code from an `IBAction` attached to various buttons. The following code just makes it grow.

```
-(void)popAnimationGrowAndShrink:(UIButton*)sender{

    const CGRect originalSize = sender.frame;

    POPSpringAnimation *animGrow = [POPSpringAnimation animationWithPropertyNamed:kPOPLayerBounds];
    POPSpringAnimation *animShrink = [POPSpringAnimation animationWithPropertyNamed:kPOPLayerBounds];
    animGrow.toValue = [NSValue valueWithCGRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, sender.frame.size.width * 1.1, sender.frame.size.height *1.1)];
    animShrink.toValue = [NSValue valueWithCGRect:originalSize];
    animGrow.springSpeed = 5;
    animGrow.springBounciness = 10;
    animShrink.springSpeed = 5;
    animShrink.springBounciness = 10;

    [sender.layer pop_addAnimation:animGrow forKey:@"grow"];
    [sender.layer pop_addAnimation:animShrink forKey:@"shrink"];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to write so much of code for this, the framework is very easy

```
-(void)popAnimationGrowAndShrink:(UIButton*)sender{

   UIButton *btn=(UIButton*)sender;
   POPSpringAnimation *sprintAnimation = [POPSpringAnimation animationWithPropertyNamed:kPOPViewScaleXY];
   sprintAnimation.velocity = [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(8, 8)];
  sprintAnimation.springBounciness = 20.f;
   [self.btn pop_addAnimation:sprintAnimation forKey:@"bounceAnim"];
}
```